# Insert into table from dynamic query IN MYSQL not working?

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I need to insert into table from dynamic query. I have try to use Prepare and Execute statement but its not working. Please help me where i do mistake.

```
SET v_SQL = 'Select * from Patient';
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS AlcoholTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  AlcoholTable ( PatientId int ,MRNNo varchar(500),Gender varchar(500))        
Insert into  AlcoholTable
SET stmt_str = v_SQL;
PREPARE stmt FROM  stmt_str;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Not working means have you got any error or not getting your expected output? If getting error then provide that error message in your question.

Comment: 2 things , 1- prepared statements only work with user defined variables (those prefixed with @) 2- the insert and select should both be included in the user defined variable (use concat). BTW if patient includes more than 3 columns you should change the select to specify only the columns you intend to insert.

Comment: actually, this is part of stored procedure which i need to convert from MSSQL to mysql , in my insert query 20 column so i used only insert query without column and when i try to execute abobe query in navicut it show error near PREPARE statement line..please help...

Comment: Please put this query in as mysql stored proceder and try to save and run .. and let me know if you find anything.. I am using navicut for connect mysql.